# Is it possible to access raw audio on android?

Tags: android, audio

I check the Internet for that answer, 
but it seems to me that we can only have access to an equalizer class 
but not to the raw audio itself.

I want to make an app that apply some transformation to the playing sound (from any application) before it gets out.

Is a rooted device a way to achieve that?

If yes can you give me some food for thought?

Comment: "I want to make an app that apply some transformation to the playing sound (from any application) before it gets out" -- that most certainly is not available via the Android SDK, for obvious privacy reasons.

Comment: Privacy reasons?  Why, if sent from his own app (as stated)?  Although if the sound is coming from your own app, you can always read in the data, process it, write it out, and play the new file.

Comment: @GabeSechan OP didn't state "from his own app" He stated explicitly: `(from any application)` Which would indeed be a huge privacy concern, because it could for instance, alter the sound coming from the telephone or voicemail apps...

Comment: My apologies, I misread.

Comment: @CommonsWare you're right, but privacy should be a concern in many other app, like the one which can read SMS (and the SDK allows it) and so on. Of course it could be used in evil ways. But that was not my question :-)

Comment: Access audio output from other apps on a rooted device: Yes, but the way you do that is platform specific, so there's no standard solution that would work on all rooted devices. Transform the audio before it gets sent to the DAC/Bluetooth chip/whatever: No. You'd have to modify Android itself in order to do that.